# Label on price scale homemade indicator

Tags: label, pine-script, indicator

I have an indicator which indicate me round numbers on a specific chart in tradingview. For exemple, on US30 or NAS100 chart, the indicator draw horizontal line on round numbers ending by xx000 or xx500. Like 34 000, 34 500, 35 000, etc. My only problem is that the price of the line is not labled in the price scale. first picture is the actual indicator. Second is how I want it to look with the label at the right scale highlighted + the number ending in xx500 in blue + number ending by xx000 in pink.
[image #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrJ6r.png)
[image #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB03O.png)

I anybody able to make me the code line to make it work please?

Here is the code in the actual version:

```
//@version=5
indicator('LVL', overlay=true)

var levels = input(5, title='Number of levels')
var lineColor = input(color.rgb(255, 00, 255), 'Line color')
var lineWidth = input(1, title='Line width')


var spacing = if syminfo.ticker == 'XAUUSD'
    25000
else if syminfo.ticker == 'XAGUSD'
    250000
else if syminfo.ticker == 'SPX500USD'
    500
else if syminfo.ticker == 'NAS100USD'
    5000
else if syminfo.ticker == 'US30USD'
    5000
else if syminfo.ticker == 'US30'
    500
else if syminfo.ticker == 'BTCUSDT'
    50000
else if syminfo.ticker == 'ETHUSDT'
    25000
else if syminfo.type == 'crypto'
    500
else if syminfo.type == 'forex'
    500
else if syminfo.ticker == 'USOIL'
    1000
else
    2500




var step = syminfo.mintick * spacing
if barstate.islast
    //label.new(bar_index, low, text=syminfo.type, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
    for counter = 0 to levels - 1 by 1
        price = if syminfo.type == 'index'
            math.ceil(close / 4) * 4
        else
            close

        stepUp = math.ceil(price / step) * step + counter * step
        stepDown = math.floor(price / step) * step - counter * step
        line.new(bar_index, stepUp, bar_index - 1, stepUp, xloc=xloc.bar_index, extend=extend.both, color=lineColor, width=lineWidth, style=line.style_solid)
        line.new(bar_index, stepDown, bar_index - 1, stepDown, xloc=xloc.bar_index, extend=extend.both, color=lineColor, width=lineWidth, style=line.style_solid)

label.new(chart.right_visible_bar_time, levels, str.tostring(levels), xloc=xloc.bar_time)
label.new(chart.right_visible_bar_time, levels, str.tostring(levels), xloc=xloc.bar_time)
```

I tried with different line like, label for exemple

```
label.new(chart.right_visible_bar_time, levels, str.tostring(levels), xloc=xloc.bar_time)
label.new(chart.right_visible_bar_time, levels, str.tostring(levels), xloc=xloc.bar_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is unfortunately not possible with `line`s.

If you can draw your lines with the `plot()` function, you can do it from your chart settings:
[image]